# Unload high-res timer module

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I am running a game server which uses more cpu% than it should. The cause is the server itself, and I have been advised to unload the high-res timers module from the linux kernel. However, I have no knowledge on how to do this.

"The SA-MP server might use slightly more CPU on linux. There are several reasons for this, but the biggest factor is that most current linux kernels have high-res timer kernel module loaded, which means thread sleep cycles are very accurate.

A server host that ran SA-MP on linux and was concerned about CPU could unload the high-res timers module in the kernel."

How could I unload the high-res timers module in the kernel?

Comment: There isn't a "high-res timers module" that can be unloaded to remove high resolution timer support from the kernel, as high-res timer support is built in to the kernel. Perhaps they are referring to the "snd-hrtimer" module.

Answer (score 0):

High resolution timers are not compiled as kernel modules, and therefore cannot be unloaded. You need to re-compile your kernel to disable high-resolution timers.

Comment: Of course they won't (built-in drivers are not loaded as modules).

Comment: So, what the point of this answer at all? HR timer is not a device with a simple driver, they are quite embedded into the core parts of the kernel.

Comment: Well, I answered the question (i.e. "how do I unload a kernel module ?") also highlighting the fact that HRT is not a module. But I see your point: I should have gone straight to the point by saying that it is not possible. Going to change the answer...